# How can I make all the child views have the same length in the table layout?

Tags: android, tablelayout

1. I used android: stretchColumns = "*" so that the children of the table all have the same width. However, the length of the children view depends on the length of the text. How can you make the child views have the same size?
2. I added a button at the end of the table layout. I want the image of this button to have the same height as the adjacent textViews while maintaining the aspect ratio. What should I do?

   ```
   <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/ET1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
           android:background="#ffffff"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="0"
           android:textColor="#000000" />            

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/ET2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
           android:background="#ffffff"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="00"
           android:textColor="#000000" />            

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/ET3"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
           android:background="#ffffff"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="0000"
           android:textColor="#000000" />            

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/ET4"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
           android:background="#ffffff"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="00000000"
           android:textColor="#000000" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btSET"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
           android:scaleType="centerInside"
           android:background="@drawable/ui_2_setbtn"/>

   </TableRow>
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

Assuming `@drawable/ui_2_setbtn` is a vector asset...

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0000"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00000000"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btSET"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ui_2_setbtn"  // or android:src="...", depends if you are using VectorDrawableCompat or not
            android:background="@color/green_dark" /> // only to if you want to make button looks same size as EditText

    </TableRow>
```

The ImageButton (and also the Button) has a little margin defined in his style. That's why it looks a little bit smaller than EditText. To change this, make a custom style for your button or as in my example, set a background colour.

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

All will share the equal length in same row.

```
<TableRow android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0000"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00000000"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btSET"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"/>

    </TableRow>
```

Please let me know if this helped.